# Versioning Binaries on OSX

Tags: macos, makefile, versioning

I have a C program that I build using Makefiles on OS X and I'd like to add the version/build number so that it is included in any crash reports. How can this be done without putting the binary as part of an app bundle?

Comment: Add the version/build number to what?

Comment: To the binary so it appears in the crash dumps

Answer (score 0):

As you may have realised, the standard OSX method is to create a bundle and add the version in the Info.plist and there isn't the usual attributes available within the binary executable, as you'd find in Windows.

Many terminal apps will allow you to discover their version with a -v option, but this is usuallly just a function returning the version number.

If you want to add meta data without hard coding it, you could use the extended file attributes to store the version number, which you can  read, write and view with the [xattr command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html).

Comment: but will crash reporter recognize my version attribute and include it in the crash report with this method?

Comment: Probably not and I don't think there's anything that would help you with that, but would be interested if anyone else knows differently. Can I suggest you edit your question and add that requirement?